# Clustered Index scan

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When I select only Id I don't see clustered index scan, But when I select a XML column I see clustered index scan.

Is not index used only for Where clause but not for select clause?

```
declare @LenderID int = null,
@LenderCode varchar(64)= null
--Add Lender Search as in Lender Maintenance
if @LenderID is not NULL
  Select @LenderCode = CODE_TX from LENDER 
     where ID = @LenderID and PURGE_DT IS NULL

 declare @StartDate datetime2 = '1/22/2014 12:00:00 AM', 
         @EndDate datetime2 = '1/24/2014 12:00:00 AM'
 select rh.id 
 from  REPORT_HISTORY rh
 where 
 (
   (@StartDate is NULL or @EndDate is NULL)
 or
   (RH.CREATE_DT between  @StartDate and @EndDate)
  )
and
(
   RH.LENDER_ID = @LenderID
or 
   @LenderCode is NULL
)
```

Also it is surprising that a database can not handle a clause like @StartDate is NULL or @EndDate is NULL and goes for index scan, it should ignore the field if it is passed as null.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the two *actual* execution plans somewhere?

Comment: It generates huge xml, I will try

Comment: How did you define your clustered index? Can you post the script that defines it?  A screen shot of the actual execution plan would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The answer will probably be based on what the query optimizer thinks of your table and index-- including, among other things, row size and the statistics that apply.

Indexes aren't magic, and they don't always help. If SQL Server opts to use an index, it should be able to efficiently seek on the index for whatever is contained in the index. But by the same token, if you ask for any information that isn't covered by the index, that data will be located somewhere else (on disk or in memory) and will need to be cross-referenced using the clustered index.

So when presented with a query, SQL Server needs to make assumptions and guess the best query plan. How many rows will the index seek return? How much data will need to be read in that process versus the expected amount to be read if it just hits the clustered index? How many times would it need to perform a clustered index seek to get additional data?

So, things to check: does your index cover the XML column? If not, how many rows will be returned by your query versus the number of rows in the main table? Are your statistics up to date? If you really want, you can use a query hint to force a specific index to be used, but you should absolutely look into these other things first.